# Mouseover overlay div stays positioned only with first result of loop

Tags: javascript, loops, mouseover, css-position

I have a script that overlays a div if you mouseover an image button.

This works great for one instance but if the results are more than one (in a mysql loop) the overlay box stays with the topmost result.  How can I make this follow and jump down with each result listed instead of just the first one?  If you mouseover each button down the list, it does popup but it's the positioning of the popup that won't move downwards.

I am sure this has to do with position: absolute vs. relative etc..  but when I change those, the script doesn't work anymore.  Not sure if there is an alternative to this overlay feature?

The end result is that I have a list of results for a client to see.  Each list has buttons where they can mouseover to see a note.

// divs that are in the loops...

```
<div style="float:left; position: relative;" onmouseover="callMouseOver()" onmouseout="callMouseOut()">
<img style="padding:0 12px 0 12px;" src="/images/llm/button-account-notes.png">
    <div id="child" class="areas_served_container shadow">
    pop up content
    </div>
</div>
```

// script that is in the footer

```
<script language="javascript">
function callMouseOver(){
document.getElementById("child").style.display = "inline";
}

function callMouseOut(){    
document.getElementById("child").style.display = "none";    
}
</script>
```

// style sheet for div that overlays

```
.areas_served_container {
display: none; position: absolute; 
top:44px; left:94px; 
z-index:999px; 
width:350px; padding:20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one element with the same `id`. It have to be unique. Then you have to add parameter to you functions. But you should use jQuery instead of inventing a wheel.